# Disable Ethernet When Not Plugged In

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet, notification

I have an Ethernet adapter that I sometimes use on my USB-C Hub. When it's not in use, Ubuntu keeps giving me "Network not connected" notifications that are really annoying, and I have to disconnect the interface from the menu.

I'd like for it to be disconnected automatically, until I plug it in. If that's not possible, I'd like for it to disable automatically, unless I enable it.

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt my `net-o-matic`, bash script to help with this: `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic` It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect.